# Maximum number of groups in Kruskal Wallis one-way analysis of variance

Tags: inference, nonparametric, assumptions, kruskal-wallis-test

Is there a maximum number of groups in Kruskal Wallis' one-way ANOVA? I am looking at a data set with 42 separate groups and I am unsure if there would be some sort of issue in running that many groups under Kruskal Wallis.

I remember reading once that ANOVA should not be ran with more than 26 groups although I am not sure what the logic behind that number exactly is

Comment: Can you say where you read this claim in relation to ANOVA?

Comment: It is just a rule of thumb I have heard from one of my statistics courses. I did a quick search on the maximum number of comparison groups and I don't really see anything substantial except for this website: http://www.physics.csbsju.edu/stats/anova_pnp_NGROUP_form.html

Comment: Thanks for that; it does suggest *somebody* must have recommended it sometime. If you do see something on such recommendations for maximum number of groups,' I'd be very curious to understand what the argument is. [There may well be one, but why 26 in particular? Why not 23 or 29 or 47? ... ]

Comment: Thats not true Glen we can use 1 way anova for more than 26 groups through R studio

Comment: @Glen_b perhaps they label the groups with the letters of the alphabet as used for writing English so there is a different limit for speakers of other languages.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no maximum number of groups, at least not based on any fundamental principle. Some specific software might, for some reason only known to the programmers, impose some limit, that is another matter.

But, if the number of groups is huge(ish), I would suspect there is some more structure to the problem so maybe some other analysis taking into account that structure should be sought.